# is it possible to have more than one instance of Elasticsearch on a single node?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search and I am trying to learn as much as I can about Elasticsearch.

I have a cluster having a single node. Is it possible for me to create multiple instances of Elasticsearch on the single node present in my Cluster?

Due to some reason, i cannot add another node to my cluster, so is it possible to install another instance of Elasticsearch on the same node and treat it as a separate node to create replicas on it?

Basically what I am asking is can I install multiple instances of Elasticsearch on a single node and treat those instances as a separate node to install replica on it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's definitely possible.

However, you need to make sure to configure both nodes properly (i.e. have separate data folders, different http/tcp ports, etc) and equally share the available CPU/RAM/HDD resources among both nodes and still leave some RAM for the OS.

Also note that it is strongly discouraged to run your whole cluster on a single node. If physical node was to crash for some reason, you'd end up with no ES cluster at all. But for learning purposes it is perfectly ok to do it in order to experiment shard allocation, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your prompt reply..
another question i have regarding single node cluster..
i have created an index with default no of shards(i.e. 5 shards) on the single node present in my cluster. However when i list all my shards i can see only one shard created for my index. Does Elasticsearch check for the total number of nodes present in a cluster before creating the index and assigning the shards(in my case i had not specified any no of shards while creating the index, so i was expecting total of 5 shards to be created for my index).
can you help me with this?

Comment: I think this should be another question as it is unrelated to the current one

Comment: No, i am fine with the answer provided here. However i do have a different  question to which i need your help @Val.

Could you please visit the below link to help me with that question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503568/moving-data-from-existing-index-to-a-new-index-with-different-data-flow-approach

Comment: I'll check the other one next

Comment: @Val..could you please help me on the below query?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503568/moving-data-from-existing-index-to-a-new-index-with-different-data-flow-approach

i am awaiting your reply..

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you have to configure unique http.port & transport.tcp.port in elastic instances

Comment: Hi @ShashankReddy, stackoverflow is about answers, not just hints to answers. Please elaborate!